# select query in user sleep state

Tags: mysql, innodb

mysql server block many query, when i use `show processlist`, i found a simple query started 30 days ago

```
Command: Query
Time: 2262201
State: User sleep
Info: SELECT `abc` FROM `xxx` WHERE `a`='a' AND `b`='b';
```

below is mysql document explain about `User sleep`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-thread-states.html

```
The thread has invoked a SLEEP() call.
```

but this query string not include SLEEP function, why cause this state?

> `xxx` is InnoDB table; mysql version is 5.7.32-log

Comment: the `xxx` table wouldn't happen to be a VIEW with a sleep statement in it? If you do the same query again does it have the 'User sleep' state?

Comment: @danblack `xxx` is InnoDB table, not view. Same query don't have `User sleep` state, and even if i add `sleep(10) ` in sql, the state always `Sending data`.

Comment: Or maybe a `TRIGGER` is involved?

Comment: Check `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` -- to see if the query happened to be truncated.  How big is `abc`?